# Structs and Classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, naming, struct

In c++ if you create a struct or class like this

```
struct foo {

}
```

Must you use the struct or class qualifier to create another one as you do in c, if not why is that? When would it be appropriate to use it in C++

Example

struct foo a;

Thanks :-)

Comment: Structs behave as public classes in C++ and create new types, so using the struct keyword to create variables is purely optional.

Comment: @rubixibuc - Added `C++` tag, as that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `struct` is not required. In C++, the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that in a `struct`, members are `public` by default, while in a `class`, they're `private` by default.

Answer (score 3):

No, `struct` keyword is not required while instantiating in C++. By the way, struct definition should end with a `;`

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you don't have to. And you better not, it's the proper C++ style if you don't intend to mix your code with pure C. The reason is that the designers of C++ thought that C's concept of tags was unnecessarily complicated. I tend to agree.

Answer (score 1):

In C you can avoid it by using a typedef. In C++ the type is created automatically hence no need to explicitly state it.

The `C` syntax to make it similar:

```
typedef struct {
....
} foo;
```

Then you can use it by saying `foo x;`